Flutter Mocktail with bloc_test: how to verify another bloc's state is changed
I try to verify the state of another bloc is changed with bloc_test but not sure how to do.
The situation is like that

BlocA has an event called SignIn
BlocB has an item in state called User, which is updated with event called UserChanged

I would like to verify that when BlocA.add(SignIn()), the User in BlocB is updated with specific values.
My current idea is
act: (blocA) {
        blocA.add(SignIn());
      },
verify: (bloc) {
        verify(() => BlocB.add(
              UserChanged(
                user: any(
                  named: "user",
                  that: isA<User>().having(
                    (user) => user.email,
                    "email",
                    "test@test.co1m",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )).called(1);
      },

But I got the following error
Invalid argument(s): An ArgumentMatcher was declared as named user, but was not passed as an argument named user.

BAD:  when(() => obj.fn(any(named: "a")))
GOOD: when(() => obj.fn(a: any(named: "a")))

Please advice how I can achieve it. Thank you
===============================================
Update: my test will pass if I do not verify the argument passed to UserChanged event, such as
act: (blocA) {
        blocA.add(SignIn());
      },
verify: (bloc) {
        verify(() => BlocB.add(any<UserChanged>())).called(1);
      },


yes, at least I did the same.
You need to check the proper states and method execution separately.
test(
  'WHEN user does smth'
  'THEN adds new states for Bloc A and Bloc B',
  () async {
    await _callUseCase();

    verify(blocA.setLoaded()).called(1);
    verify(blocB.setChanged()).called(1);
  },
);

So the test above is for that use case:
class UseCase {
 const UseCase({
required this.blocA,
required this.blocB,
required this.repoA,
});

final BlocA blocA;
final BlocB blocB;
final RepoA repoA;

Future<bool> call(Payload payload) async {
  final List<Account> accounts = blocA.state.allTradingAccounts;
  try {
    blocA.setUpdating();
    final result = await repoA(payload);
    blocA.setLoaded([
      result,
      ...accounts,
    ]);
    blocB.setChanged(MyType.real);
    return true;
  } catch (error, stack) {
    blocA.setLoaded(accounts);
    return false;
  }
}


Thank you @Iaroslav, my understanding for your example is that blocA does not directly invoke events in blocB, blocA and blocB are siblings. Is my understanding correct? Seems like the test could not verify the accounts passed to setLoaded function is as expected and also same for that for blocB. Please correct my if I am wrong. Thank you

Yes, blocs are not supposed to affect each other. They should not know about each other. This way leads to coupling
Instead, I'd recommend using a usecase, which includes both blocs.
In your case, once a user signs in the usecase makes blocs to update their state. So you need to test the usecase, and new blocs' states emission.

Thank you @Iaroslav, I think this might be a better practice. I will change my code a bit.

I think it's not the best idea to test the way you want.
I would prefer to have 3 tests:

Check the state of Bloc A on the SignIn event
Check the state of Bloc B on the UserChanged event
Mock Bloc A and Bloc B and verify that the respective state update methods of both Blocs were called


Hi @Iaroslav Siniugin, thank you for your idea. Could you please elaborate the third test? Do you mean we only verify the state update method is called but don't verify the arguments passed to the state update method? Is it correct?

I think the main problem is the verification of your parameter. Instead of putting everything inside the verify with having etc., you should consider using captureAnyNamed.
Your code then would look like this:
final user = verify(
  BlocB.add(UserChanged(user: captureAnyNamed("user")))
).captured.single;
expect(user, isA<User>().having(
    (user) => user.email,
    "email",
    "test@test.co1m",
  ),
);
// if your user class has == and hashcode overridden 
// it should be sufficient to check it like this
expect(user, expectedUser);


Hi @pawelsa, thank you for your advice. I am not sure what's the difference between mockito and mocktail. I am using mocktail and it only has captureAny(named: "user"). However, I still get the same error.

Just to make sure that you are obtaining correct data, check what captured returned. Verify if the runtimeType is what you expect, and then display contents of the class. If both of them are as expected, maybe you are missing overridden == and hashcode
